To locate the indices of DataFrame entries containing specific strings
How do I find the indices of DataFrame entries containing specific strings and these strings are not column names.
indice0 = np.argwhere(df=='apple')
indice1 = np.argwhere(df=='banna')
indice2 = np.argwhere(df=='orange')

I know that the code above works, but is there a way that I can simplify this like using a for loop. And it seems like the code above doesn't work if I just know part of a string, for example
indice0 = np.argwhere(df=='pple')
indice1 = np.argwhere(df=='anna')
indice2 = np.argwhere(df=='range'

Are there other ways to locate the indices?

For the first question you can directly index the index where the condition holds. Combine this with isin([...]) your example becomes:
indices = df.index[df.isin(["apple", "bananna", "orange"])]

For the second, I am not aware of a general case version of isin for suffixes but you can do it separately through df.index[df.str.endswith("pple")]. Alternatively, if the variants are few then you could manually create a regex like df.index[df.str.contains("pple|ananna|range$")]
